# file reading writing using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io

I want to make a program in java in which one thread is reading a file and other is writing in

it. Anybody please provide me any reference link where I can find the code snippets for the

same?

Comment: Have you tried a search engine? I hear Google is quite good these days...

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow aren't intended to replace search - you're essentially asking "where is this stuff on the internet"? Instead, if you want to try to build an application, and post code that you've tried to write, and with which you're having a specific problem, we'd be happy to help with that question.

Comment: Re: Nick, yes, please do Google this. The link below was the first Google hit for "Java Threading Sun".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't read and write to a file at the same time. In the best case, you'll end up with corrupted data, or an IO error.

If it's for inter-process communication, you should instead use sockets or higher-level systems like JMS.

Answer (score 0):

[The Java Concurrency Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).