# Writing and Reading from/to same file

Tags: java, multithreading, io

Is it possible to read and write same text file in same time?

First thread will add text strings to the file, it will add "ending" string when there is no data.

Second thread should read data from that file and block if there is more new data. it should end when it reads "ending" string.

```
public class TheFileReader implements Runnable {


    public void run() {

        FileInputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader fbr = null;
        File file =  new File ("C:\\temp\\fileout3.txt");
        String s1 ="";

        try {       
            fbr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file), 1024*1024);

            while (s1.equals("exit")==false){
            s1 =fbr.readLine();
            if (s1==null){
                s1="";              
                Thread.sleep (50);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(s1);         
            }           

        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try {
                fbr.close();                        
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

public class TheFileWriter implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        FileOutputStream os = null;
        BufferedWriter fbw = null;
        File file =  new File ("C:\\temp\\fileout3.txt");
        String s1 ="";

        try {       
            fbw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 1024*1024);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                fbw.write("test" + i);
                fbw.newLine();
            }
            fbw.write("exit");

        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            try {
                fbw.close();                        
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

UPDATE:

if I add  `fbw.flush() after  fbw.newLine();` I think it will work.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to design a database.  You might want to use the real thing instead.

Comment: Looks like the same question as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607169/file-reading-writing-using-multithreading/8607215#8607215

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could do something like use a BlockingQueue as your go-between. Poll it until something's there, then write it to the file in the second thread. The first thread just keeps popping String objects into the queue as they are read.

There's lots more complicated ways to do this, but that's an easy and dirty way.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I don't hink I can even access same file from 2 threads.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Do you really want this done by two threads? That's a horrible way to do just about anything. If you're trying to pass data back and forth using a File as a semaphore, that's bad too. Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: And to be more murky: nothing will stop you from opening up a FileReader and FileWriter on the same file in different threads, but you'll get unpredictable results depending on when and how you write to the file. It seems like you're trying to use a File to co-ordinate data transfer.

Comment: yes, I use File to co-ordinate data transfer, this is done as backup. (if some process fails)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a file to coordinate, make it a random access file that exists within a third party object with a synchronized method, say

```
public synchronized String readWrite(boolean read, string writeStuff);
```

That accepts a boolean operator to determine if you want to read the info or write the info. Then pass a second string with the data you wish to write. If you decide to read instead, use the return value as your output.